# How to solve this problem and change this lock screen?

Tags: kde, lock-screen, .desktop, gdm

Until last night I was using Ubuntu's default Windows environment. I don't know which Ubuntu's desktop was that. Maybe it was GDM.

Last night I installed KDE Plasma Desktop via Terminal. I did not like it. So I uninstalled it and came back to Ubuntu's default desktop. Everything is the same again. But the lock screen has become like the picture below it has never been before.

This lockscreen hangs a lot. It doesn't take me to the desktop even after entering the password. Even the keyboard mouse doesn't work. I can enter by turning off the PC and turning it on again.

What kind of problem is it? How can I solve it?

> Note: My OS Ubuntu 20.04

**My PC**

Intel core i3 10 Generation

RAM 8 GB

SDD 120 GB

Gigabyte H410M H V2 motherboard

This lock screen was not there before..
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lock screen is provided by a software called "Display Manager" (DM).
Default Ubuntu 20.04 DM is `gdm3`.

Run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

And select `gdm3`.

You might need to restart.

Comment: After giving the following commands, my display is not coming..  apt remove sddm
   sudo systemctl enable gdm

Comment: Why did you run that command?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't enter your Ubuntu desktop environment at all to run the needed command, you may have to enter a tty to even run said command to fix the display manager. To enter a tty you must use Ctrl + Alt + Fn keys ([instructions](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=how%20to%20open%20tty%20ubuntu)) Once you are in a tty you will have to login, then change the default display manager to back to gdm3 with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

just like @pLumo suggested (I previously had to do something similar), then restart.